# Buildout and zc.recipe.egg:scripts : strange behavior while generating an interpreter

Tags: python, buildout

I use `zc.recipe.egg:scripts` in order to generate a `bin/python` script that will be able to import my develop-eggs (in a custom buildout based project). My `buildout.cfg` looks like this :

```
[buildout]
develop =
    develop-eggs/MyPackage.MyLib
    develop-eggs/MyPackage.MyLib2
    develop-eggs/MyPackage.MyLib3
parts =
    interpreter
    [...]

[interpreter]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
interpreter = python
eggs =
    MyPackage.MyLib
    MyPackage.MyLib2
    MyPackage.MyLib3
```

All worked fine (as always) until I add the `MyPackage.MyLib3`. This one does not want to be included. I checked the `setup.py`, the `buildout.cfg` nearly 10 times, and I began to investigate on the `zc.recipe.egg:script`.

What i found was... strange. This is the first time I see that, and I have no idea what's happening.

In the `zc.buildout-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py` egg file line 1169, I added 2 little lines in order to see what happened :

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

And it worked. The script was well generated this time and I could import the `MyPackage.MyLib3`. I tried to remove the pdb lines, but again, the script doesn't include the `MyPackage.MyLib3`. **I did NOT do anything while I was on the PDB interface** (just some *next* and *continue*).

Tested 3 times, and 3 times the same : if I edit the file `zc.buildout-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py`, then the `bin/python` script is well generated ; but if I undo my edits, the script does not include the develop-egg `MyPackage.MyLib3`.

Do you have any idea from what it could come from? Maybe it's not the right way to generate a Python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

In fact, generating an interpreter named python is not a good idea : some other scripts are also generating a specific site-package interpreter. Then I just changed my `interpreter` section as following :

```
[interpreter]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
interpreter = py # avoiding conflicts with some other interpreters
eggs =
    [...]
```

And now I execute my script with `bin/py`.